# How to avoid MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, exception

I am using Java to insert some data into mysql . But having apostrophe(punctuation mark) into data (near's weekly tracker suggests that job growth) it gives me MySQLSyntaxErrorException.Please give me proper solution to handle that

Code I have isa

```
void insert(String a1,String a2, String a3) {
  String nt = a2;
  String pt = a3;
  String tb = a1; 
  query = "insert into "+tb+"(head,des) values('"+nt+"','"+pt+"')"; 
  try {
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    System.out.println("inserted"); //con.close();
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    // Logger.getLogger(conec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: 'void insert(String a1,String a2, String a3)
    {
        String nt = a2;
        String pt = a3;
        String tb = a1;
  
       query = "insert into "+tb+"(head,des) values('"+nt+"','"+pt+"')";
        try {
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println("inserted");
            //con.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
           // Logger.getLogger(conec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }'

Comment: @ToukirNaim : Edit your question and add this query there..

Answer (score 6):

[Use query parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), not string concatenation. This will allow the database driver to format the values you send to the database server, rather than re-inventing this wheel yourself.

```
String sql = "insert into ... values (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, nt);
stmt.setString(2, pt);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
query = "insert into "+tb+"(head,des) values('"+nt+"','"+pt+"')";
```

should be

```
query = "insert into "+tb+" (head, des) values ('"+nt+"','"+pt+"')";
```

Please do these changes and let me know if there are still problems....

Comment: no getting same error .MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'heart rates change when they hear different signature whistles.')' at line 1

Comment: do you have statement "heart rates change when they hear different signature whistles" in your code anywhere?? I think  there is problem somewhere else...

Comment: those have apostrophe the query can not handle

Comment: ahhh can you post that string here with apostrophe??

Comment: ( test whether dolphins' heart rates change when they hear different signature whistles.) thats the type of data i have to insert

Comment: Please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188552/error-while-inserting-data-having-single-quotes-between-it) it will help you...